# How to change the default error messages displayed by Django forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I have created a form in Django which has a charfield with max_length=255 as follows:

```
task = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
```

Now I want to let the user know how many characters he has typed if he exceeds the 255 characters limit, so I did the following

```
if form.is_valid():
    #some code
else:
    messages.info(request,(form.errors.get("task").as_text()))
```

now suppose if I  type **445** characters in the form field and submit then **by default I am getting the following error message:**

```
* Ensure this value has at most 255 characters (it has 445).
```

**but instead, I want to change this message to:**

```
Error: maximum length limit is 255 characters (it has 445).
```

**So I tried the following:**

```
class ListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ListModel
        fields = ["task", "status"]

        error_messages = {
            'task': {
                'max_length': ("Error: maximum length limit is 255 characters"),
                
            },
        }
```

**Now the message has been changed to:**

```
* Error: maximum length limit is 255 characters.
```

**My Problem:**

1. I don't want the `*`  which is being displayed in front of the messages
2. I was not able to capture the number of characters the user has typed, which was being displayed in the default message i.e. `(it has 445)`

What can I do to print
`Error: maximum length limit is 255 characters (it has 445).` instead of
`* Error: maximum length limit is 255 characters.`?

Comment: Could you show us the `HTML` for the form? I am pretty sure the asterisk `*` is an HTML `<li>`.

Comment: I have used the [Django form class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django) to generate the form, so I've not defined any HTML exclusively for the form.

Comment: Sure, but the problem is how you are acessing the `messages.info` in your template. For me `messages.info` does not contain an asterisk if I access it without any HTML tags. The standard `django.forms.Form` class does not render any HTML for the `messages.info`, you have to access it by yourself.

Comment: Okay now I got your point, to access the message in HTML I am doing the following: 
`{% if messages %}{% for message in messages %} <p>{{ message }}</p> {% endfor %}{% endif %}`, so I don't think I am using any <li> class in my HTML

Comment: Strange. Maybe you could try putting `messages.info(request, "some test string")` and tell us if there is still the same issue. You could also try `print(form.errors.get("task").as_text())` to see if there is an asterisk there or if it is an HTML issue. Also the parentheses is redundant

Comment: `messages.info(request, "string")` simply displays the string without any `*` but  yeah the `* ` appears even on `print(form.errors.get("task").as_text())`. Actually if I do `print(form.errors.get("task"))` then it prints `<ul class="errorlist"><li>"some_string"</li></ul>` so the <li> class is within the `form.errors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want the * which is being displayed in front of the messages

The problem as you finally came to the conclusion (in the comments) is in

```
form.errors.get("task").as_text()
```

This sends to the client a `<ul>` HTML element and not the plain text. So what you can do, to solve this problem and your **other problem** is simply check if `max_length` can be found in `form.errors` and use your own `string`. The following should go in your view after `form.is_valid` has been called

```py
# After this point form.is_valid() has been called
if "max_length" in form.errors:
    task = request.POST.get("task") # Get the text that was entered in `task`
    length_of_task = len(task) 
    # Simply send your own message
    messages.info(request, f"Error: maximum length limit is 255 characters (it has {length_of_task}).")
```

Note a few things here

- Accessing the data by using `request.POST.get`

**@SaeX** Pointed out that you can use `self.cleaned_data.get` to get The data that was sent in the POST request. While this is true, **it only works if `form.is_valid` has returned true**. You can find out more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735545/how-to-access-data-when-form-is-valid-is-false).

- What if I want to catch multiple errors and use a dictionary

You can still use a dictionary but for values you will have to use functions. Something like the following

```
def handle_max_length(data):
    datalen = len(data) > 255 # Do your stuff
    
def handle_some_other_error(data):
    pass 

errors = {
    'max_length' : handle_max_length,
    'some_other_error': handle_some_other_error
}

def myView(request):
    # ... code
    form = MyForm()
    if not form.is_valid():
        for field in form.errors:
            field_value = request.POST.get(field)
            for error in field:
                messages.info(
                    request, errors.get(error)(field_value) # Getting the function and calling it with the data
                )
```

Comment: okay so I printed `form.errors` it is something like this: `<ul class="errorlist"><li>item<ul class="errorlist"><li>Ensure this value has at most 255 characters (it has 445).</li></ul></li></ul>`, so `max_length` is not present in `form.errors` and so the condition `if "max_length" in form.errors` will always return False. But still your solution solved my problem, as when form.is_valid() is False we don't need `if "max_length" in form.errors` anymore, we can directly do `if length_of_task > 255` and print the message.Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Accessing `request.POST` and doing your own validation, most of the time is a better choice. Note that in a few edge cases, when you might be sending files you can only access the data from `request.POST` once (the file data). Otherwise everything works normally.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `clean_<fieldname>()` in your form like:

```
def clean_task(self):
    task = self.cleaned_data.get("task")

    if len(task) > 255:
        raise ValidationError("Error: maximum length limit is 255 characters (it has %s.") % len(task)

    return task
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: `if len(task) > 255:`

Comment: after adding the function in my form, do I need to call it somewhere in my views.py because after adding this I am getting the default message `* Ensure this value has at most 255 characters (it has 445).` instead of the custom message

Comment: This will only work when `form.is_valid()` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

It's been 2 years and a half since you asked this question...
But I have found a better solution so I write it here for anyone who visits this question in the future!
So let me explain.

I could do it by editing `clean` function in `forms.Form` based classes.

```
from django import forms


class myForm(forms.Form):
    text_field = forms.CharField(
        min_length=20,
        error_messages={'min_length': 'Minimum length is 20 but you entered {}!'}
    )

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()

        text = self.errors.get('text_field', None)

        if text:
            for i, x in enumerate(text):
                if x == self.fields['text_field'].error_messages['min_length']:
                    self.errors['text_field'][i] = x.format(len(self.data[f'{self.prefix}-text_field']))
```

Also for `forms.ModelForm` object we can do it as below:

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models


class myModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    text = models.TextField()


class myModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['text'] = forms.CharField(
            min_length=20,
            error_messages={'min_length':'Minimum length is 20 but you entered {}!'}
        )

    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = ('title',)

    def _post_clean(self):
        super()._post_clean()

        text = self.errors.get('text', None)

        if text:
            for i, x in enumerate(text):
                if x == self.fields['text'].error_messages['min_length']:
                    self.errors['text'][i] = x.format(len(self.data[f'{self.prefix}-text']))
```

**`_post_clean` is a function that will run when clean process has finished, and `forms.Form` object has no methods like this**

I have tested them and they work fine.

#### CAUTION

**For `forms.ModelForm` objects make sure to create custom field in `__init__` function, using validators in model won't work!**

**Also by creating custom field, everything you defined for target field in `Meta` class will be ignored, and you have to define them in `__init__` function**